# Creating CSV file as an object

Tags: powershell, csv, wrapper

I have got a robust script which gets, parse and uses some data from .csv file. To run the script I can use

> .\script.ps1 -d data_file.csv

The thing is I cannot interfere into script itself that is why i need to create some kind of a wrapper which will create new csv file and use script.ps1 with a new made file. I am wondering if there is a possibility to create a csv file as an object which will be passed directly to the command like this

> .\script.ps1 -d csv_file_as_object.csv

without creating file in some path directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'd need in this case is the **equivalent of Bash's [*process substitution*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)** (`<(...)`), which, in a nutshell, would allow you to present a command's *output* as the content of a *temporary file* whose *path* is output:

```
.\scripts.ps1 -d <(... | ConvertTo-Csv) # !! does NOT work in PowerShell
```

<sup>Note: `... | ConverTo-Csv` stands for whatever command is needed to transform the original CSV in-memory.</sup>

**No such feature exists in PowerShell** as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1, but it [has been proposed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4284).

*If* `.\scripts.ps1` happens to also accept *stdin* input (via pseudo-path `-` indicating stdin input), you could try:

```
 ... | ConvertTo-Csv | .\script.ps1 -d -
```

*Otherwise*, your only option is to:

- save your modified CSV data to a *temporary file*
- pass that temporary file's path to `.\script.ps1`
- remove the temporary file.